# Hadoop Ambari cannot confirm hosts

Tags: hadoop

I tried to use Ambari to manage the installation and maintenance of the Hadoop cluster.

After I started ambari server, I use the web page to set up Hadoop cluster.

But at the 3rd step-- confirm hosts, the error shows below

And I check the log at /var/log/ambari-server, I found:

> INFO:root:BootStrapping hosts ['qiao'] using /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server cluster primary OS: redhat6 with user 'root' sshKey File /var/run/ambari-server/bootstrap/1/sshKey password File null using tmp dir /var/run/ambari-server/bootstrap/1 ambari: master; server_port: 8080; ambari version: 1.4.1.25
>
> INFO:root:Executing parallel bootstrap
>
> ERROR:root:ERROR: Bootstrap of host qiao fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (1)
>
> INFO:root:Finished parallel bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you provide ssh rsa private key or paste it?
and  from the place you are installing, make sure you can ssh to any hosts without typing any password.
If still the same error, try

ambari-server reset

ambari-server setup

Comment: I tried, but it seems not useful.
The error also the same:
INFO:root:Executing parallel bootstrap
ERROR:root:ERROR: Bootstrap of host qiao fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (1)

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/forum/installing-hdp/ .       It is the forum of hontonwork,the ambari committer, and the link is  specific for ambari and HDP installation problem,there are the many ambari developer there.

Answer (score 0):

Pls restart ambari-server

**ambari-server restart**

and then try accessing Ambari

It would work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can ssh to every single host on the list, including all master hosts.

To do this, ensure that Ambari host's .ssh/id_rsa.pub entry is included in every hosts' .ssh/authorized_keys file. Then ssh from Ambari's host to every single server - and check if it is asking for your password. You can use a tutorial like http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/ to check if everything has been done properly.

You need to do the same on the Ambari host itself, if you added it to hosts list.